# Structure for update with 1 where?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I have actually this UPDATE and work perfect, but I want add other WHERE:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET an = an + 20 WHERE name = '$name' ";
```

To this

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET an = an + 20 WHERE name = '$name' and WHERE age = '$age' ";
```

I need do it, and UPDATE only if that 2 `WHERE` are correct.
Please help.

Comment: Only one `WHERE` clause, not 2.  Just `AND`.

Comment: you need `AND`: `...WHERE name='$name' AND age='$age'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Great, it work thanks :D

Comment: @RobinZigmond Great, it work thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat the `WHERE` keyword, the `AND` is enough.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET an = an + 20 WHERE name = '$name' and age = '$age' ";
```

There can be only one `WHERE` clause in a query and it is introduced by the keyword `WHERE`. If you have more expressions to filter by use logical junctors like `AND` or `OR` to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Just take out second where

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET an = an + 20 WHERE name = '$name' and age = '$age' ";
```